# correct way to retrieve object data in a separate module

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, feathersjs

I'm developing an API which also serves as a telegram bot. I need to retrieve all `telegram-user` in order to alert them.

```
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const config = require('../config/production.json');
const TOKEN = config.bot.token;
const bot = new TelegramBot(TOKEN);

const app = require('./app.js');
const users = app.service('telegram-user');

router.post(`/${TOKEN}`, (req, res) => {
  bot.processUpdate(req.body);
  res.sendStatus(200);
});


bot.onText(/\/registrar/, async function onStartText(msg) {
  users.create({
    id: msg.chat.id,
    first_name: msg.chat.first_name
  }).catch(() => {
    bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'Usuario ya registrado');
  });
  bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'Registrado correctamente');
});
```

I've tried several ways to make const 'users' work but either I get undefined or app.service is not a function.

I've also tried changing `require('.app.js')` with

```
const feathers = require('@feathersjs/feathers');
const express = require('@feathersjs/express');
const app = express(feathers());
```

if I run this exact code in app.js it works:

```
const users = app.service('telegram-user');
users.create({
    id: msg.chat.id,
    first_name: msg.chat.first_name
  })
```

I'm using feathersjs with Sequelize and Postgresql

UPDATE: 
If I put `require('.app.js')` inside the function it works, but if I put it at the beginning of the fail I receive "app.service is not a function".

This works:

```
bot.onText(/\/registrar/, async function onStartText(msg) {
    const app = require('./app.js');  //require in here
    const users = app.service('telegram-user');
    users.create({
            id: msg.chat.id,
            first_name: msg.chat.first_name
    }).catch(() => {
            bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'Usuario ya registrado');
        });
    bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'Registrado correctamente');
});
```

How can I set `app` as a const variable in the file?

Comment: How does your `app.js` look like? Requiring it at the beginning of the file is a pretty common practise and should work if it is exported properly.

Comment: Here it is, pretty much standard (it was generated with feathers-cli) https://pastebin.com/DatbMiPK

Comment: This is why it seems odd. It could be that the service isn't there (`users.create` is not a function) but I can't think of a way that `app.service` wouldn't be available in this case. It's the first time I'm seeing this.

Comment: is it correct to assign `app` to a `const`? do you have by any chance any working example that I can check? Thanks

Comment: Yes it is. The [feathers-chat](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-chat) shows how to use this, e.g. in the [users service tests](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-chat/blob/master/test/services/users.test.js).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was had a circular dependency that made `require('.app.js')` return an empty object. Solution was to move the `require` that loaded my first code section to the bottom of `app.js` so that `app` is fully started before it gets loaded by `require('.app.js')`